# How to search data among all html table elements using jquery with ignoring pagination?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to filter data from html table. But my html table contains pagination. So like on first page there are 10 results. Then if i am searching data it is searching only in these 10 results but i want this to filter data from all table elements not only from these 10.

```
$('#upen').keyup(function(e) {      
                // create the regular expression
                var regEx = new RegExp($.map($(this).val().trim().split(' '), function(v) {
                    return '(?=.*?' + v + ')';
                }).join(''), 'i');

                // select all list items, hide and filter by the regex then show
                $('.product-listing-table tbody tr').hide().filter(function() {
                    return regEx.exec($(this).text());
                }).show();
```

});

Comment: how is pagination done? If it is done on server, then you need to do filtering on server also.

Comment: How to do that filter results on server ?

Comment: It depends on how it is implemented, but generally you could send a search phrase in ajax request to the server and it would return matching records in response, paginated or not.

Comment: Take a look how it is done with datatables http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html You have pagination, sorting and filtering on server or client

Comment: Any other solution except datatables